# Dependent Filter Issue :- If the parent Filter value is changed then the dependent filter with previous selected value is not getting removed

Tags: apache-superset

How to reproduce the bug

1. Create a Filter Name A
2. Create a Filter Name B
3. Tick the checkbox the Values are dependent on other filters in Filter B and select A in VALUES DEPENDENT ON
4. Click on Save
5. Select some value in filter A
6. Data API call will be done for Filter B and the option will be updated.
7. Select some value in Filter B. For Example, Selected Asia.
8. Remove the Filter Value in Filter A and select some other option.
9. Data API call will be done for Filter B and the option will be updated.
10. In Option of Filter B previously selected will be present and it's not coming from the Result of Data(API Call).
11. https://jam.dev/c/2e22ee9e-d1b2-48ba-a063-11dfe2584c8a
12. https://jam.dev/c/54743133-2a1e-4d79-bfa4-30e0d8cdc95c
13. https://jam.dev/c/bad93252-6c4c-4ade-bd7b-53108b245692
14. https://jam.dev/c/2e343713-d305-4b3d-b504-8c5d48b75647
15. https://jam.dev/c/5f3fa04b-c25f-4ea9-9108-c1059a3f9caf
16. https://jam.dev/c/c963fc06-e234-422e-85f5-60a8b7592574

**Expected results**

If The Previously selected value is not present in the result of the dependent filter API call it shouldn't be present in the option or in the selected state.